# What is the name of the wooden hook support on the walls of traditional Japanese rooms?

Tags: words

Traditional (and even not-so-traditional) Japanese rooms have wooden panels running along the walls, about 1m from the ceiling.

They are mainly used to affix hooks, to which clothes hangers, paintings etc. can be hung (they also make for a convenient way to conceal cables around the room, but I doubt that was their original purpose).

**There must be a specific (Japanese) name for it. What is it?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe they're called [[長押]{なげし}](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%95%B7%E6%8A%BC).

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I was also able to find some illustration that might be better at explaining what I meant: http://www.bluestone.co.jp/meiboku/zousakuzai/nageshi.htm

Comment: Note for those that have furigana turned off on the site, that here `長押` is read `なげし`.  However, in this age of technology, it has also come to be read as `ながおし`, meaning "long press" or "hold", esp. of buttons, touchscreens, etc.  Though this reading may also have the accompanying okurigana as `長押し`.

Comment: My family and I always called it [鴨居]{かもい}! And now I know we were all wrong! lol

Comment: @Chocolate: didn't know 鴨居 either... Thanks for mentioning it!